# How to implement back arrow(Up Button) in the vertical center of the Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

When adding back button in Toolbar in landscape mode, back button is not in the vertical center of an toolbar.

Only thing I do is in android manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="tack.hardcode.com.tack.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

Here is my toolbar code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#3F51B5">

   </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I also have v21.styles implemented and i have include toolbar in my mainActivity.

What else should I do?!

Comment: Do you want to implement back arrow (I.e. Up navigation) or do you want it to be in vertical center? @KiZo

Comment: It is already implemented, i only want to be in vertical center of an app_bar

Comment: Can you post your toolbar code? I mean xml.

Comment: I have posted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set toolbar height to `wrap_content` causes this problem. `Actionbar` height is always 56dp in portrait and 48dp in landscape. (For mobile devices)

If you are setting `wrap_content` as height for toolbar then it took same height for both portrait and landscape. So in portrait mode, up button remains in center while in landscape it goes up and empty space added to the bottom.

So, change toolbar height to `android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"`.
By changing this, toolbar takes the same height as `actionbar` for both in portrait and landscape mode.

Hope it helps to you. And I hope now you are clear.

Comment: it works, thank u very much, although i do not understand why am I using actionBarSize for Toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Toolbar mToolBar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar (mToolBar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar ();
    actionBar.setElevation (5);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I already did this and back button is still not in vertical center of an app_bar. Back button is working nice but i want it to be in vertical center on the left side. Now it is on the left side but not in vertical center.